# PowerShell HTML Element Variable

Tags: powershell, ui-automation

I'm trying to capture all HTML elements that match a specific string to run through a foreach loop. The first iteration works as intended, but when it hits the foreach the second time I get an access denied error (0x80070005). When I output the variable, its a System._ComObject, but each element is blank.

I've tried manually starting the foreach at the second element in the array and it works fine. It is just losing the variable data somewhere during the function.

What am I missing?

```
$global:ie = New-Object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$global:ie.visible = $true


function RunReport
{
$link.click()
start-sleep 5

$global:ie.Navigate("link to reporting home page")
start-sleep2
}

$global:ie.Navigate("link to reporting home page")
start-sleep 2

$links = @($global:doc.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName('div')) | Where-Object {$_.InnerText -like 'Report Name - Batch*'}
$links | foreach {
$link = $_

RunReport
}
```

Comment: Why are you recursing the function inside the final foreach loop?. Why `start-sleep 2` after the Navigate() and not wait until ie is no longer busy with `while ($global:ie.Busy -and $global:ie.ReadyState -ne 4) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 }`? Why go for `global` at all and not define $ie inside the function?

Comment: All good feedback. Most of the page is loaded via JavaScript and the built in IE busy functions weren't catching that. Any tips for my issue with the variable?

Comment: Whete do you define `$global:doc` ?

Comment: Good catch. I had that originally defined in my "WaitForPage"  function, but stopped using that function due to the JavaScript loading issue. I've added that function back in above the start-sleep and still have the same issue.

Comment: However, when I do the following, it works. (but its really ugly)


`$links = @($global:doc.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName('div')) | Where-Object {$_.InnerText -like 'Report Name - Batch*'}
$i=0
$links | foreach {
$linksv2 = @($global:doc.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName('div')) | Where-Object {$_.InnerText -like 'Report Name - Batch*'}
$link = $linksv2[$i]

RunReport
$i++
}`

Comment: I think I figured it out. When I navigate back to the reporting home page at the bottom of the RunReport function, the uniqueNumber and uniqueID fields are different than they were when the page was originally loaded. Guess I'll stick with the ugly approach above.